# How can I use MIDISend to play a midi file on a connected synthesizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am wondering if someone has any insights on how to send a midi file to a connected synthesizer? I played with MIDISend and MIDIPacketList but all the notes end up playing at the same time. I then tried to use dispatch_after and call MIDISend with individual notes this way but I am getting some very strange behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried to set timestamp to future time?

Comment: Thanks @JohnTracid that helped a lot but I am now having trouble with setting an accurate timestamp. My research suggests that I should use mach_absolute_time() and add the number of ticks represented by each note but I can't quiet get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to set the timestamp on the packet as John Tracid mentioned.